# Why does this code repeatedly show a KeyError?

Tags: python

I have been to write a Python code for an assignment, and I'm struggling hours without success. The question is:

> Write a program that reads 10 numbers from the input and at the end prints the number that has the largest number of divisors against the prime number along with the number of divisors of the prime number in the output. If several have this mode, print the largest of them.

Sample input:

```
123
43
54
12
76
84
98
678
543
23
```

Output:

```
678 3
```

Here is what I did:

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
d = input()
e = input()
f = input()
g = input()
h = input()
i = input()

digits = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
avval = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)

adad = {}

for av in avval:
    for digit in digits:
        if int(digit) % av == 0:
            adad[digit] += 1
        else:
            adad[digit] = 1

print(adad)
```

The code shows `KeyError` on every run.
Any idea how to get this code (or maybe a better idea) to work?

Comment: `adad[digit] += 1` -- before add value you should set the key or use the defaultdict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `your_dict[n]` must be defined if you want to be able to use the += operator on the corresponding value. If it's not defined before, it will have no value, but since the += operator needs a value to add something to, a key error is thrown.

Maybe you could do something like this instead:

```py
#...
if int(digit) % av == 0:
            value = adad.get(digit, 0)
            adad[digit] = value + 1
        else:
            adad[digit] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly smaller case:

```
In [5]: digits
Out[5]: ['3', '4']
In [6]: aval = (3,4)
```

your code:

```
In [9]: adad = {}
   ...: 
   ...: for av in aval:
   ...:     for digit in digits:
   ...:         if int(digit) % av == 0:
   ...:             adad[digit] += 1
   ...:         else:
   ...:             adad[digit] = 1
   ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-9-262b0c28be2f>", line 6, in <module>
    adad[digit] += 1
KeyError: '3'
```

It's trying to find '3' in `adad`.  But `adad` is empty:

```
In [10]: adad
Out[10]: {}
In [11]: digit,av
Out[11]: ('3', 3)
In [12]: int(digit)%av
Out[12]: 0
```

The `if` test passes, so it's trying to add to that entry.  Hence the `keyerror` - every time you run this.  Repeated tries aren't going to solve the problem.

Note that I show the full error - with traceback.  That tells me where the error is.  You should have also noted that.  Secondly I then check the values of the variables at that point.

As others told you, even if there's a match with `av` you still need to initialize the key.

for code like this, `defaultdict` is a convenient variation on `dict`

```
In [21]: from collections import defaultdict
In [22]: adad = defaultdict(int)
    ...: 
    ...: for av in aval:
    ...:     for digit in digits:
    ...:         if int(digit) % av == 0:
    ...:             adad[digit] += 1
    ...:         else:
    ...:             adad[digit] = 1
    ...: 
In [23]: adad
Out[23]: defaultdict(int, {'3': 1, '4': 2})
```

It automatically initializes the key.